# chmod 775 on a folder but not all files under that folder

Tags: unix, chmod, chown

by assigning 775 rights of user to a folder (project) does that impact the files permissions under the folder?

```
# chown -R root:user1 /var/www/project/
# chmod 775 -R /var/www/project/
```

Meaning, if `/project/config.html` used to have a 664 right does that mean that 664 right disappears and grants 775?
How to avoid this to happen? There are files and folders with different rights under `/project/` and I do not want these to be overridden.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Remove the `-R` [flag](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html). That means it changes all files and folders in the subdirectory as well.

```
# chown root:user1 /var/www/project/
# chmod 775 /var/www/project/
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes : -R means recursive. Remove -R